# Get form data in Backing Component from Composite Component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

My Composite Component contains the following form:

```
<cc:interface componentType="answerCompositeComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="AnswerType" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.AnswerType" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="ItemSource" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.Answer" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="QuestionId" type="java.lang.Long" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <input jsf:id="sc#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.answerId}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

How can I access the value of the `<input jsf:id="sc#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.answerId}" />` in my Backing Component? I tried the following in my backing bean in the overriden `processUpdates` method.

```
Answer ItemSource = (Answer) getValueExpression("ItemSource").getValue(context.getELContext());
String formid = String.format("sc%d", ItemSource.getAnswerId());
String get = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(formid);
```

`String get` is always null. Is there a way to get the value of the input?

PS: I know that using plain html in jsf is not the purpose of it. I'm just interessted how my plan is achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used plain html with jsf attributes, so I don't know if it's applicable.

Generally, this is a common way to access nested components in a composite:

```
<cc:interface componentType="answerCompositeComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="AnswerType" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.AnswerType" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="ItemSource" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.Answer" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="QuestionId" type="java.lang.Long" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="questionInput" binding="#{cc.input}" />

    <!-- maybe something like this might work
        <input jsf:id="questionInput" jsf:binding="#{cc.input}" />
    -->
</cc:implementation>
```

where

```
@FacesComponent("answerCompositeComponent")
public class AnswerCompositeComponent extends UINamingContainer
{
    private UIInput input;

    @Override
    public void processUpdates(FacesContext context)
    {
        super.processUpdates(context);

        Object value = input.getValue();
        Object localValue = input.getLocalValue();
        Object submittedValue = input.getSubmittedValue();

        // do your things with values 
    }

    public UIInput getInput()
    {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(UIInput input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

Note that a composite backing component is a `NamingContainer`, so prefer static (or none at all) nested component IDs. Avoid dynamic IDs, unless you really need them and you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Many thanks! That works for me. Don't rly. no if its related to the issue - Is there a way to tell jsf to use the id attribute instead of the name attribute? I got here a list of radio inputs which I need to group with attribute name.

Comment: JSF sets **both** *id* and *name* to the same value in the generated html, for UIInput components. The html input *name* attribute is required by html container *<form>* itself, otherwise it would not know which and how to pass key-value-pairs within the submit request. Maybe I misendertood what you're asking?

Comment: Ahokay. Would it also be possible to get the generated html code of the composition component in the method processUpdates and search for the `<input id="questionInput" ` and assign its value manual to the Answer model?

Comment: I tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604962/get-rendered-html-code-in-backing-component-from-composite-component