# Get rendered html code in Backing Component from Composite Component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

How can I get the posted form data in the backing component in the 
`processUpdates` method?

```
@Override
    public void processUpdates(FacesContext context) {
//get here rendered html code
}
```

Or can I get the posted form data in the `decode` method?

[Edit]:
My goal is to get the posted form data - Not to get the generated html code (Sry I wasn't precisely)

Comment: Trying to get input values from generated HTML is crazy. You have a full fledged server-side framework which has the main goal to simulate stateful communication. Please post your xhtml (facelets) code, so I can understand what you are trying to achive, not what you are trying to solve :) maybe you want something like [PrimeFaces **custom layout** radio button input](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml)?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I'm sry, I tried to say, that I need to get the posted form data, not the generated html. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to achive, yet. I mean, at high level.

`UIComponent.decode` and `processUpdates` are medium-level lifecycle APIs which should be overriden when you want to **extend** the framework.

If you just need to **use** the framework, you need a *managed bean*, not a *backing component*.

Furthermore, *generally* only components that extend `UIInput` need to hook in those phases, because they are bound to a `value="#{...}"` value expression (which in turn refers to a *managed bean*, in most cases), and need to synchronize those values with the bound expression.

I suspect you are uselessly complicating your life: hooking into medium or low-level APIs is a real pain if you don't have an excellent understanding about how the framework operates.

Anyway, the standard request parameters *decode* into input component is this:

```
String clientId = this.getClientId(context);

Map<String, String> requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

String newValue = requestMap.get(clientId);
if (newValue != null) 
{
    this.setSubmittedValue(newValue);
}
```

Please, post the full xhtml facelet code (not the composite one, but the facelet *using* that composite), so I can understand where you want to go and I can try to point you to the right tool to use.